# Define sprite shapes for touch

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, shapes, ccsprite, cgpath

I'm trying to add shapes to my sprites, wich are in NSArray, using this code:

```
theSprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite1"];
sprite1.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, sprite1.contentSize.height/2);
[self addChild:sprite1 z:3];
sprite1Path=CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(sprite1Path, NULL, 0, 286);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite1Path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite1Path, NULL, 768, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite1Path, NULL, 768, 208);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite1Path, NULL, 356, 258);
CGPathCloseSubpath(sprite1Path);
[theSprites addObject:sprite1];

CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite2"];
sprite2.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, sprite2.contentSize.height/2);
[self addChild:sprite2 z:4];
sprite2Path=CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(sprite2Path, NULL, 0, 254);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite2Path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite2Path, NULL, 768, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite2Path, NULL, 768, 144);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite2Path, NULL, 494, 168);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(sprite2Path, NULL, 204, 212);
CGPathCloseSubpath(sprite2Path);
[theSprites addObject:sprite2];
```

Then i'm trying to specify that only **theSprites** are moovable. I created a function like in one of cocos2d tutorials.

```
- (void)selectSprite:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
CCSprite *touchSprite = nil;
for (CCSprite *sprite in theSprites) {
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {            
    touchSprite = sprite;
    }  }  }
```

And now i'm stack! 
And i don't understand how to change CGRectContainsPoint to CGPathContainsPoint...
I don't know how to specify both shapes whith one statement... or create if ()  if () constraction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems.  First, you need to attach the path to the sprite.  You should subclass `CCSprite` and give it a `boundingPath` property:

#### MySprite.h

```
@interface MySprite : CCSprite

@property (nonatomic) CGPath shapePath;

@end
```

#### MySprite.m

```
@implementation MySprite

@synthesize shapePath = _shapePath;

- (void)setShapePath:(CGPath)path {
    CGPathRetain(path);
    CGPathRelease(_shapePath);
    _shapePath = path;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    CGPathRelease(_shapePath);
    [super dealloc]; // if you're using ARC, omit this line
}
```

You then set the `shapePath` property when you create the sprite:

```
MySprite *sprite1 = [MySprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite1"];
// ... blah blah blah all the stuff you did to init sprite1 and sprite1Path
CGPathCloseSubpath(sprite1Path);
sprite1.shapePath = sprite1Path;
[theSprites addObject:sprite1];
```

Now you can test for the touch in the sprite like this:

```
- (MySprite *)spriteAtPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    for (MySprite *sprite in theSprites) {
        CGPoint spriteOrigin = sprite.boundingBox.origin;
        CGPoint pointInSprite = CGPointMake(point.x - spriteOrigin.x, point.y - spriteOrigin.y);
        if (CGPathContainsPoint(sprite.shapePath, NULL, pointInSprite, false))
            return sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i'm tryind to add `@property (nonatomic) CGPath shapePath;` there is a "Must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'CGPath'". Do i need to add 'struct'?